# Change index column text in pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

I have the following spreadsheet that I am bringing in to pandas:

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwgAF.jpg)

I import it with:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("sessions.xlsx")
```

Jupyter shows it like this:
[Panda Dataframe 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jBLH.jpg)

I then transpose the dataframe with

```
df = df.T
```

Which results in this 
[Transposed DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu48f.jpg)

At this stage how can I now change the text in the leftmost index column?  I want to change the word **Day** to the word **Service**, but I am not sure how to address that cell/header.  I can't refer to column 0 and change the header for that.

Likewise how could i then go on to change the A, B, C, D text which is now the index column?

Comment: Hi there, please [edit] your question to add any output/data as *text*, not an image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could first assign to the `columns` attribute, and then apply the transposition.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("sessions.xlsx")
df.columns = ['Service','AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
df = df.T
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the columns before transposing would work. To do exactly what you want, you can use the the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function. In the documentation it also has a helpful example on how to rename the index.

Your example in full:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("sessions.xlsx")
df = df.T
dict_rename = {'Day': 'Service'}
df.rename(index = dict_rename)
```

To extend this to more index values, you merely need to adjust the dict_rename argument before renaming.

Full sample:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("sessions.xlsx")
df = df.T
dict_rename = {'Day': 'Service','A':'AA','B':'BB','C':'CC','D':'DD'}
df.rename(index = dict_rename)
```